# How to upload files to Azure via Laravel with same structure as on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, azure, file-upload

I have a wordpress based website which has more than 1000 posts and relevant images (more than 5k), galleries etc. Now the project has been converted to Laravel. I would like to migrate/move all the images from Media of existing wordpress to new Azure server where Laravel project is hosted. I'm already able to successfully upload one be one file with Request method to Azure server by setting up default storage to Azure. But not sure how I should upload all the files/images from existing wordpress to Azure with Laravel so that same folders/files strucutre and names are maintained as currently on wordpress.

Btw, I already have extracted sql/csv/json list of all the absolute paths of images from existing wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with Laravel / WordPress + I am not even sure I got your question right. But, it might still be useful for you. So let me know

If you have a certain structure of files within directories and you want to maintain that, you can simply upload your directories recursively to Azure's Storage account.
Check the blob storage option, Create a container.
And there is a wide variety of ways to upload your files to it, one of the most simple ways is to use AzCopy (CLI tool proposed by Microsoft)
If you wish to stick with REST API, that's an option too.

Hope I got it right

Take care